# Lombok + Play Framework 1.4.5 compatibility

Tags: java, playframework, builder, playback, lombok

I'm trying to use @Builder annotation from Lombok 1.18.2 and not work

The model class

```
@Builder
public class SubStatus{
    String name;
}
```

Use

```
SubStatus.builder().name("name").build()
```

The error

```
Error raised is : The method builder() is undefined for the type SubStatus
```

Comment: Failing to see what relevance Play Framework has to this example.

Comment: Sorry, I have not brackets in my original code. The problem is the same.

Comment: The problem is with how you compile this code; you haven't given any details about how you are compiling. Maven? Gradle? javac? ecj? some IDE?